# Precisando de Ajuda em exercicios sobre Vetor em C

Tags: c, array

Por que não está exibindo os 15 números?
E como fazer pra incluir 3 números no início desse vetor?

```
int main()
{

   int v[30];
   int i,x;

   for(i=0; i < 15; i++)
   {
       printf("Digite 15 numeros");
       scanf("%d", &v[i]);
   }
   printf("%d Os numeros escolhidos foram:", v[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas colocando `v[i]` no print, você não consegue imprimir porque não está indicando qual é o índice i. Para imprimir todos você deve fazer um laço da mesma forma que fez para ler, mas com um printf em vez do scanf:

```
for(i=0; i < 15; i++){
    printf("%d\n", v[i]);
}
```

Fiz apenas isso e rodou. (Também adicionei o `include <stdio.h>` no início do arquivo mas suponho que você já tenha colocado).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E como fazer para adicionar 3 números no inicio desse vetor?, obg pela primeira resposta

Comment: É só você colocar o número no índice que quiser, assim: v[0] = 20;
v[1] = 21;
v[2] = 22;

Comment: aah entendi agora, você quer adicionar mais três números mas manter os que já estavam? pra isso acredito que tenha que deslocar os números atuais para outras posições, tipo v[3] = v[0]; v[4] = v[1]; v[5] = v[2]; (mas tem que fazer isso para todos os elementos do vetor, então pode fazer um for com v[i+3] = v[i];) aí sim pode colocar novos valores nas primeiras posições.